# How can I convert 4D to 2D with 524288 elements?

Tags: matlab

An audio signal is saved as `.mat`. I want to convert `.mat` to `.wav` and save it. I use the following code:

```
  load S0001.mat
  filename = 'S0001.wav';
  y = x;
  audiowrite(filename,y,16000);
```

The following error occured:

```
Error using audiowrite (line 109)
Data must be a 1-D or 2-D numeric array.
```

How can I convert 4D to 2D to save `audio.wav`?

Comment: The answer purely depends on the nature of the data, what each of the dimension mean. Only you know that!

Comment: What variables are stored in `S0001.mat` and what do they represent? What do the dimensions in `x` represent?